# Run parallel test methods which are dependent with different parameter using Data Provider in TestNg

Tags: java, testng

I want to run test methods which are dependent and use ITestContext, to run in parallel with different parameters using Data Provider in TestNg. I am trying to call the test class pragmatically.

The code looks like this:

```
package com.ExploringTestNg;

import java.util.Random;

import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ParallelMethodTest {
    
    @Test(dataProvider = "dataprovider")
    public void testclass1(ITestContext context,String deviceId) {
        
        long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        System.out.println("TestClass1 is being called and context is being setup");
        System.out.print("The thread id is "+id);
        System.out.println("device id is "+deviceId);
        context.setAttribute("deviceId",deviceId);
    }
    @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"testclass1"})
    public void testclass2(ITestContext context) {
        long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        System.out.println("TestClass2 is being called and context is being retrieved "+(String)context.getAttribute("deviceId"));
        System.out.println("The thread id is "+id+"\n");
    }
    @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"testclass2"})
    public void testclass3(ITestContext context) {
        long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        System.out.println("TestClass3 is being called and context is being retrieved "+(String)context.getAttribute("deviceId"));
        System.out.println("The thread id is "+id);
    }
    @DataProvider(name = "dataprovider",parallel = true)
    public Object[][] getDataFromDataprovider(){
        return new Object[][]
                {
                    {"1001"},
                    {"1002"},
                    {"1003"}
                };
    }
}
```

```
package com.ExploringTestNg;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.testng.TestNG;
import org.testng.xml.XmlClass;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;
import org.testng.xml.XmlTest;

public class DynamicXMLSetuo  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
        suite.setName("TempSuite1");
        XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
        test.setName("Functional usecase 1");
        List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();
        classes.add(new XmlClass("com.ExploringTestNg.ParallelMethodTest"));
        test.setXmlClasses(classes);
        
        List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
        suites.add(suite);
        TestNG tng = new TestNG();
        tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
        tng.setThreadCount(5);
        tng.setParallel(XmlSuite.ParallelMode.METHODS);
        tng.run();
    }

}
```

My functionality is to call the test class multiple times with different parameters and the classes being called should run parallelly

Comment: Please mention the issue that you are facing

Comment: The method testclass1 is being called 3 times, but I want the whole sequence to be called and not just one method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with this is that the `testclass1` would be invoked three times, but the `testclass2` and `testclass3` would be invoked only once because, the execution of those methods does not depend on the number of times `testclass1` is executed. It only depends on whether `testclass1` passed or not. To solve the issue, you need to use `@Factory`

```java
public class ParallelMethodTest {

    private final String deviceId;

    ParallelMethodTest(String id) {
        this.deviceId = id;
    }

    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public static Object[][] dataProvider() {
        return new Object[][] { { "1001" }, { "1002" }, { "1003" } };
    }

    @Factory(dataProvider = "dataProvider")
    public Object[] createInstances(String id) {
        // The factory method uses the dataProvider to initialize
        // multiple instances of the test class.
        return new Object[] { new ParallelMethodTest(id) };
    }

    @Test
    public void testclass1() {

        long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        System.out.println("TestClass1 is being called and context is being setup");
        System.out.print("The thread id is " + id);
        System.out.println("device id is " + deviceId);
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = { "testclass1" })
    public void testclass2() {
        long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        System.out.println("TestClass2 is being called and context is being retrieved " + deviceId);
        System.out.println("The thread id is " + id + "\n");
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = { "testclass2" })
    public void testclass3() {
        long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        System.out.println("TestClass3 is being called and context is being retrieved " + deviceId);
        System.out.println("The thread id is " + id);
    }
}
```

With this, there is no need for storing the `deviceId` in test context as the corresponding `deviceId` would be available in the class itself.

**UPDATE** : To run in parallel, you need to do one more thing inside `DynamicXMLSetuo`.

```java
suite.setParallel(XmlSuite.ParallelMode.METHODS);
```

By adding `ParallelMode.METHODS`, TestNG will run all your test methods in separate threads. Dependent methods will also run in separate threads but they will respect the order that you specified.

Comment: So my functionality that I have generalized here is to make API calls with different device id, the id that I get in response would be passed as a key value through ITestContext. I have to make multiple calls to the API to test the load/ performance. Making it a sequence of API calls in order to test the whole process.

Comment: @Aditya, In that case, you could add `responseDeviceId` field in the class and then set the value to this from the response.

Comment: Would it not create a problem when we want to have parallel running of the testcases?

Comment: @Aditya I have updated the answer. To run tests in parallel, you need to have `suite.setParallel(XmlSuite.ParallelMode.METHODS);`.